# Error after installing Realm: Must first create RPC session with a valid host

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, realm

I recently installed realm using:

```
npm i realm -S
react-native link realm
```

**Important edit**
This issue only occurs when debugging from device

Everything still works but this time, when I try to enable `Debug Js Remotely` from the development menu, I get the error `Must first create RPC session with a valid host`.
Remote debugging used to work and the development server is still running on port 8081 as it used to be.

If there is any code example you want, please let me know. Realm is not invoked until later.

From package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ExampleProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^20.0.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "^0.44.0",
    "react-native-device-detection": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-orientation": "git+https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation.git",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.1.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "realm": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Error:[image: Screenshot]

Realm's [Issue tracker](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen) mentioned it once "somewhere" but I couldn't find a fix.
Has anyone seen this message before and can you point me in the right direction to fix this?

Comment: I'm seeing this too really annoying and slows us down. Would love to know a solution also

Comment: @ajonno, I don't expect an answer to this soon. So I posted my findings. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a better answer in the future or not at all. So, here's what I found.

I'm not really sure what solves this issue. At least, make sure that realm's port (8082 by default) is reachable on your device by commanding `adb forward tcp:8082 tcp:8082` in a terminal.

Furthermore, make sure the device is connected(!) to the same subnet/network to avoid any packet dropping.

Try completely removing the app from the device (reset) in combination with shutting down the packager and re-running `react-native run-android` / running from xcode.

I don't believe there is a uniform solution yet at the time of writing.

Comment: check on error screen, in my case it said error was related to 8083 port.

Comment: I'm not sure what has changed since I posted this. Maybe you have another plugin installed that uses port 8083? Or you changed Realm's default port?

Comment: Yes, maybe something related to realm. Here the point is error will say which one port is. Just apply your solution to these port.

Comment: [Furthermore, make sure the device is connected(!) to the same subnet/network to avoid any packet dropping]  This is the most important actually.  When debugging on  a mobile device without connecting to the wifi,  Realm will keep throwing error : [Must first create RPC session with a valid host].

Comment: @Rufus Probably yes, I guess I didn't want that to be the headline because 90% of the people reading this would role their eyes back saying "duh". As would I... Just up until I notice the obvious error. At that point my eyes would role back far enough to see the inside of my skull :)

Answer (score 0):

Along with deleting the app from the simulator before re-running, I also erased previously cached contents and settings on the simulator by going to: `Device -> Erase All Contents and Settings ...` . After this, I restarted the simulator and ran the application and then, the aforementioned error specified by the author, was gone.