# XMLHttpRequest error in ReactNative Debug mode

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I delete my android emulator and create a new one after this when i build my react native project and active **debug** mode this error appears on emulator but i dont have any problems with Previous emulator :

`Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost:8083/create_session'.`

and this on browser's console :

`Must first create RPC session with a valid host`

what should i do?

Comment: This answer can be usefull for your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44016885/error-after-installing-realm-must-first-create-rpc-session-with-a-valid-host

Comment: @Tutcugil I just change my emulator's system image from  API level 29 (Android 10)  to API level 28 (Android 9) and it work